# What does "Give in it" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does "Give in it" mean in this sentence?

> The shoes may seem tight at first, but the leather has plenty of give in it.

And when can I use it?

Comment: See the [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give) (scroll down to entry 2 of 2 - it's a noun here, not a verb).

Comment: but it's "give" and not "give in" like in that sentence, why is that?

Comment: If something has a quality such as give, flexibility, hardness, etc, we can add the phrase 'in it' in conversation, but 'in it' is not really necessary.

Comment: according to google, 'give' means also 'capacity to bend or alter in shape under pressure; elasticity', so those shoes have kinda full elasticity, the elasticity is IN the shoes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other users have shown, ***give*** as a noun means

> something's ability to bend or move from its normal shape to take extra weight or size ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/give_2))

What you are confused about is the preposition ***in*** after ***give***, which makes you think that this is a phrasal verb. Well, it isn't. Think of your sentence in this way:

> ... but the leather has ***something*** in it.

That something is a quality, and this leather has ***plenty of it***. The last two words of your sentence, ***in it***, simply mean: ***in the leather*** and can be left out. It may seem clearer to you if we replace ***give*** with ***elasticity***:

> The shoes may seem tight at first, but the leather has plenty of
> ***elasticity*** (in it).

Your sentence may be pronounced by a shop assistant trying to convince a client to buy these shoes. Or it can be the sound advice of a friend.

Comment: "In it" are extra words which don't add any meaning. This steel beam has plenty of strength (in it).

Comment: Correct, I had in mind to say that they can be dropped, but omitted it. I will include it now, thank you for pointing it out.